# Easiest way to shift a piece of malloc memory

Tags: c

I need to shift a piece of malloced memory down. Currently I am creating a temp piece of memory and then copying it over and them recopying it back with the shift

```
void * buf = malloc(5);
void * temp = malloc(5);

memcpy(temp, buf, 5); 
memset(buf, 0, 5);
memcpy(buf, temp + 1, 4);
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm curious. Why are you doing this? What is your goal that this is in aid of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, use `memmove`:

```
char * buf = malloc(5);   // pointer arithmetic only on chars!

memmove(buf, buf + 1, 4);
memset(buf + 4, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Aren't you shifting it the wrong way... you're shifting it up one. It should be `memmove( buf, buf+1, 4 );` and `buf[4] = 0;` Yes?

Comment: `buf[4] = 0` would do instead of the memset.

Comment: @JimBalter: I'm assuming the OP actually has somewhat larger amounts of memory to move...

Comment: Fair point if you mean moving the memory further; the amount isn't relevant. But you're right, memset is more general.